# Creating a GUI in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, input

I am creating a small program, and I would like to know the simplest way to make a GUI. I tried wxPython, however, it only supports 2.6 and 2.7. Are there any good, simple ones for Windows, python 3.X?

Comment: simplest? Tkinter since you almost certainly already have it installed.

Comment: [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) is built on top of Tkinter (but has no other dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best module for me is PyQt. You have all kinds of stuff, from regular GUI to 3D OpenGL and graphs and designer with all that. If not that try with tkinter, I had better experience with PyQt but you can try both and see which is better for your needs !

Answer (score 0):

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/) is another option, although I don't believe it will currently build to a Windows executable (you would run it by invoking the Python VM).

Answer (score 0):

In the [Python Wiki GUI Programmimg section](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) you can see a good comparative with a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

If you use anaconda it comes with [qt designer](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtdesigner-manual.html) already installed. Short of downloading qt creator, which is a full blown ide and requires a lot of space, this is the best option in my opinion. You can build ui's quickly and export code in either python or c++.